# How to configure PHPStorm to debug on IIS

Tags: iis-7, php5, debugging

I installed PHP 5 on IIS on a Windows 7 64 bit machine using the Web Platform Installer. I am using PHPStorm as my PHP IDE but cant find any documentation on how to get debugging to work. PHPStorm launches my PHP web application but breakpoints do not get it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

rams, you have to configure php for debugging. I would recommend you checkout [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/). Here is more information on setting up [Xdebug and PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-xdebug.html).